# How to be sure that the .kv file is completely loaded (on_parent does not solve this issue)

Tags: python, kivy, benchmarking

I'm trying to build a somewhat modular App, and because of this I'm loading new .kv files in on the fly:

```
def load_centralWidget(self, name):
    filename = name + '.kv'
    pathToFile = Path('kv/'+filename)
    if pathToFile.is_file():
        self.root.container.clear_widgets()
        filename = Builder.load_file('kv/' + filename)
        self.root.container.add_widget(filename)
    else:
        log.debug('File ' + filename + ' does not yet exist!')
```

Now I try to do load some information from a textfile and fill that into a Label:

in the .kv file:

```
CentralWidget:
    BoxLayout:
        id: outerBox
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: self.size
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        on_parent:
            app.loadRunAdjustments("findMe")
        Label:
            id: findMe
```

in the .py file:

```
def loadRunAdjustments(self, lbl_id):
    textInput = self.root.container.children[0].ids[lbl_id]
    #doing some file loading stuff here
    textInput = #loaded string from file
```

(Code is shortened, but I think I got all the interresting lines)

If I try to run that code, I get an "IndexError: list index out of range"-Error. Debugging into the code tells me, that children is an empty List. I use this function often at later moments. Then all works fine. So I think the Problem here is, that the loaded file is not fully loaded, when on_parent is called.

Is there an option/event/something else to be absolutely sure everything is loaded and the children (and its ids) are existent?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Haven't tested this, but could you move the `on_parent` into the `Label` itself? Like `on_parent: app.loadRunAdjustments(self)`. Then the `lbl_id` argument would be the actual `Label` and no `ids` access would be required.

Comment: Haven't tried it eigther but this wouldn't really solve the actual Problem because (I told you I shortened the code) I have actually five textInputs and ten labels belonging to them. So if I would do it like you suggested, I would have to call the function 15 times instead of just one time. To me that doesn't seem be good style.But thx for your suggestion!